# Unity game admob Rewarded video got Event:onAdFailedToLoad result ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads, rewardedvideoad

I am Add Admob in my unity game,but when show Rewarded video got Event:onAdFailedToLoad result ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL, why? How to solve this issue?
https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob/issues/54

Comment: Usually that's a configuration issue. Check all of your settings on the Admob website and make sure you're using the right ad unit ID.

Comment: There's not enough detail in the question here to give an answer, I think. Can you show your code and/or config as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL means that there was no ad available for your app at this time and place.